# Show all Nodes and Relationships in Data Browser Tab

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I show all nodes and relationships in Data Browser tab?

What are sample index queries that I can type in in search field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a little help icon beside the search field, if you hoover over it it shows the syntax.

If a property of your nodes and relationships is indexed you can search for all of them like this.

```
node:index:indexname:fieldname:*
rels:index:indexname:fieldname:*
```

Answer (score 55):

You may also want to try a cypher query such as:

```
START n=node(*) RETURN n;
```

It's very obvious, and it will return all the existing nodes in the database.

EDIT : the following displays the nodes and the relationships :

```
START n=node(*) MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m;
```

Comment: it only return node,adding match n-[r]-() and return n,r to see further relationship

Comment: Completely forgot about the relationships!

Comment: With version 1.9.5 (I MUST use that) it returns the nodes, but it does NOT show them...

Comment: Just to note this only matches nodes that have a relationship. If you want all use `START n=node(*) MATCH (n)-[r]->(m),(o) RETURN n,r,m,o;`

Answer (score 41):

More simple way is

```
MATCH (n) RETURN (n)
```

Comment: This is the proper way to produce all nodes and then the Data Browser Tab will magically add the relationships to the view.

Answer (score 18):

```
MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() RETURN n, r;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can show everything with simple `MATCH (n) RETURN n`, as offical documentation [suggests](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-match.html#match-get-all-nodes).

`START n=node(*) RETURN n` from Neo4j 2.0 is [deprecated](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-start.html):

> The `START` clause should only be used when accessing legacy indexes
>   (see [Chapter 34, Legacy Indexing](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing.html)). In all other cases, use `MATCH`
>   instead (see [Section 10.1, “Match”](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-match.html)).

Answer (score 5):

I found that this worked, retrieving all nodes including orphans, and all relationships:

```
MATCH (n) MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN n, r
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, that is a horrible query, since you don't include the match n node in the second match. It would probably end up with a Cartesian product returns A LOT of redundant data.
Might I suggest:
```cypher
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-(m)
RETURN n,r,m
```

Answer (score 1):

Other good way for get ALL nodes (and nodes without relationship) :

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n UNION START n = rel(*) return n;
```